# Module Import in PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, django-allauth, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my webapp on PythonAnywhere and am running into an issue which is just giving me a Error code: Unhandled Exception page. I am getting this error below in the error log:

```
  2016-07-21 06:41:49,331 :Error running WSGI application
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
        app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
        raise e
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
        app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
        raise e
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 179, in <module>
        application = load_wsgi_application()
      File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 175, in load_wsgi_application
        return __import__(os.environ['WSGI_MODULE'], globals(), locals(), ['application']).application
      File "/var/www/www_mywandermust_com_wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
        application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
        django.setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
        module = import_module(entry)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: No module named 'allauth'
```

I have already installed django-allauth in the server system and everything works perfectly on my local installation. I am also able to get the path in the console to allauth:

```
(venv) 06:49 ~/carmen (master)$ python -i /var/www/www_mywandermust_com_wsgi.py                                                                 
>>> import allauth
>>> print (allauth)
<module 'allauth' from '/home/gsussman/carmen/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allauth/__init__.py'>
```

Here is my WSGI file:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/gsussman/carmen'  # use your own username here
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'travelapp.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allauth` is installed in a virtualenv (it's called venv). Your web app is clearly not using that virtualenv (the Django referred to in the traceback is in /usr/local, not in venv)